# How to stop Zoom from stealing URI associations when installing with FlatPak?

Tags: mime-types, flatpak, telephony, zoom

Ever since installing Zoom Flatpak I've noticed that many web-links (like telephone numbers) that should **not** be associated to ZOOM are now being opened by ZOOM. I'd like to maintain Zoom assocition only for `zoommtg` and nothing else.

Looking inside `var/lib/flatpak/exports/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache` reveals that zoom is stealing file and URI associations for TEL (telephone) CALLTO as shown below

```
[MIME Cache]
application/x-zoom=us.zoom.Zoom.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/callto=us.zoom.Zoom.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/msteams=com.microsoft.Teams.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/tel=us.zoom.Zoom.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/zoommtg=us.zoom.Zoom.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/zoomphonecall=us.zoom.Zoom.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/zoomus=us.zoom.Zoom.desktop;
```

How to stop it from stealing all these other associations?